# Smarty variable in all template

Tags: php, html, prestashop, smarty

i'm creating new module for prestashop 1.6. 
i've registered this module (named spedizioneassicurata) on extraCarrier hook.
In the install function i've

```
public function install()
{.....
     return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('header') &&
            $this->registerHook('extraCarrier') &&
            Configuration::updateValue('spedizioneassicurata', '6');}
```

i've also:

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
{
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'spedizioneassicurata.tpl');
}

public function hookDisplayHeader()
{
  $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/spedizioneassicurata.css', 'all');
}

public function hookextraCarrier($params)
{

    $summary = $this->context->cart->getSummaryDetails();
    $total_products = $summary['total_products_wt'];

    $tax_insurance = Configuration::get('spedizioneassicurata');

    $tot_ins = $total_products * $tax_insurance / 100; 
    $this->smarty->assign(array('tot_ins' => $tot_ins));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'spedizioneassicurata.tpl');
}
```

now i'm able to see my var tot_ins in my tpl file spedizioneassicurata.tpl
but when from order-carrier.tpl (where i select the carrier and i see my var) i go to order-payment-classic.tpl (where there is the resume of my order and where i want to check my variable) i don't see my variable tot_ins

Why??

i've to initialize my var in hookheader?

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope problem, you cannot access your variable outside your module template. A solution could be to use another hook like hookPayment for instance.

Comment: ok. so i've to add a  public function hookPayment($params) and in this hook i can use my variable?

Comment: You can if you invoke a template etc.